# How do you calculate the covariance "stack up" of relative measurements?

Tags: covariance, stacking

Say that you have a measurement of $x_1$ relative to some globally fixed datum and a covariance for it, $\sigma_1$. If you have another measurement, $x_2$, taken relative to $x_1$ with its own covariance, $\sigma_{2-1}$, how would you evaluate the value of $\sigma_2$ relative to the globally fixed datum?

Would it just be: $\sigma_2 = \sigma_1+\sigma_{2-1}$? This seems overly simple and inaccurate as approximately half of the time, the two uncertainties might have opposite signs and cancel each other out.

Background:

I'm a mechanical engineer by degree, doing research in controls and optimization. I'm trying to determine how to combine the uncertainty from a GPS\IMU (x,y,z,phi,theta,psi measurements) with measurements relative to the GPS location (such as a range sensor). I'm familiar with worst-case engineering tolerance stack ups, but want to know if there is a better way when dealing with sensor covariances rather than engineering tolerances. My end goal is simply to find the correct covariance values to input into a kalman filter.

Comment: I would love to know why whoever downvoted this did so. Is it a poorly worded question? Is there an answer to this posted elsewhere that I was not able to find when I was searching before? Please let me know! I would love to improve the quality of my questions but can't do so without feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I would still like verification or correction from someone with far more experience myself, I have found what I believe to be the answer at [Sigmetrix.com](http://www.sigmetrix.com/tolerance-stack-up/).

The solution would be a "1D RSS":

$\sigma_{ASM} = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 \bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

This is how a tolerance stack up would be statistically calculated (not worst case). I believe this same relationship would hold for covariance.

Comment: I would love to know why whoever downvoted this answer did. Is it wrong? Please let me know!